# How do I solve "[Error] invalid use of incomplete type 'class SLLNode'" Linked Lists

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying so solve this error I am getting when i try to pass a Linked list to another class that i have. I have looked through other questions but non of them seem to fix this problem.

I also need SLLNode to stay in ListAsSLL because it is a parent to other classes

DynamicSizeMatrix is supposed to have an aggregation to ListAsSLL

My DynamicSizeMatrix.cpp file

```
#include "DynamicSizeMatrix.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cassert>
#include<cstdlib>
#include"ListAsSLL.h"

using namespace std;

DynamicSizeMatrix::DynamicSizeMatrix(SLLNode* sll,int r, int *c)
{

    rws = r;
    col = new int [rws];
        for(int x=0; x < rws; x++) // sets the different row sizes
        {
            col[x] = c[x];
        }

    SLLNode *node = sll ;
//  node = sll.head;

    *info = new SLLNode*[rws];
    for (int x= 0; x< rws;x++)
    {
        info[x] = new SLLNode*[col[x]];

    }

    for(int x=0;x<rws;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<col[x];y++)
        {
            info[x][y] = node;
            node = node->next; // My error happens here 

        }
    }


}
```

my "DynamicSizeMatrix.h"

```
#include"ListAsSLL.h"   
#include "ListAsDLL.h"
#include"Matrix.h"
#include"Object.h"
class SLLNode;

class DynamicSizeMatrix : public Matrix
{

private:
    SLLNode*** info;
    //Object* colmns;
    int rws;
    int *col; //array of column sizes
    //  int size;

public:
    DynamicSizeMatrix()
    {
        info = 0;
        rws = 0;
        col = 0;
    }
    DynamicSizeMatrix(SLLNode* sll,int r, int *c);
//......
```

and "ListAsSLL.h"

```
class ListAsSLL : public List
{
    //friend class LLIterator;
    friend class DynamicSizeMatrix;
    protected:

        struct SLLNode
        {
                Object* info;
                SLLNode* next;
            //  SLLNode(Object *e, ListAsSLL::SLLNode* ptr = 0);
        };

        SLLNode* head;
        SLLNode* tail;
        SLLNode* cpos; //current postion;
        int count;

    public:

            ListAsSLL();

        ~ListAsSLL();
        //////////////
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `SSLNode` is declared as nested class of `ListAsSLL` but forward declared outside of that scope. Move it out from `ListAsSLL`'s scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class ListAsSLL, from the point of view of an external class using it, it only has access to the public members. As you can see your SLLNode is in the `protected` section.

So you have two options really (well, actually there are quite a few), but here are two that keep it encapsulated in the same file as least:

1. Move SLLNode declaration into a `public` section and then use it like: `ListAsSLL::SLLNode` instead of just `SLLNode`.
2. Just move it outside of the class to make it accesable to all who include "ListAsSLL.h".

I prefer method 1 since it keeps the scope smaller/more relevant, but there is not much in it really.... eg:

```
class ListAsSLL : public List
{   
    public:
        struct SLLNode
        {
                Object* info;
                SLLNode* next;
        };
        ListAsSLL();

    protected:
        SLLNode* head;
        SLLNode* tail;
        SLLNode* cpos; //current postion;
        int count;
```

Comment: now in my other classes thats using SLLNode is saying SLLNode does not name a type

Comment: @JaynillGopal this will solve your problem, but it is risky to allow the users of the liked list access to the nodes. This solution breaks encapsulation and allows users of the linked list to modify the list's state. For example, a user could maliciously or by mistake `myNode.next = some_other_address;` and break the list.

Comment: @user4581301 - no,  only the struct is in the public section. The nodes themselves are in the protected section - safe and sound :)

Comment: @JaynillGopal - Did you make the struct public within ListAsSLL? - then you need to use it like: `ListAsSLL::SLLNode` because it is a class within the ListAsSLL.

Comment: option 2 helped. I need SLLNode in other classes as well so that fixed ,y issue thanks

Comment: The only reason to make `SLLNode` `public` is if `SLLNode`s are being passed out of the object. You can safely pass copies and `const` references, but as soon as the list gives a `SLLNode *`  or a `SLLNode &` to a node to a client, it doesn't matter what access the list stores the node under. The client has direct access to the node and can do anything they want with that pointer, including `delete node;`. The object no longer has control of its state, so encapsulation has been broken. If you are going to restrict access to a member, never pass it to the user without strings attached.

Comment: @user4581301 It is a good point. But I can't speak for OPs design - I would say his entire list should be only modified within one class, and has special "accessor" functions to restrict access to internal list workings/data. But that is not OPs design. So, just in the way that OP is trying to make his two classes work together (not necessarily optimal), I am not trying to re-write his code and since the other class is a friend it has access to all the protected members anyway... so it matters not - its already "broken".